# UML Class Diagram Association vs Dependency

Tags: java, architecture, uml, class-diagram

Let us say we have Class A, Class B, and Class C

Class A has an object of Class B:
array = ArraList

Class A then passes this array to Class C

When drawing the class diagram
which logic is the correct one:

Class A has an association with Class B and Class B, and Class C has a dependency with Class B

OR

Class A has an association with Class B, Class C has an association with Class A, and Class C has a dependency with Class B

Or are the both wrong? If so, what is the correct way of representing the following case in a class diagram?

Comment: @bruno I agree. I simply was asking what is the best representation for this case. I hope the one who marked this question reconsiders!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Class A has an object of Class B: array = ArraList

I suppose you mean *Class A has the attribute 'array' being an 'ArrayList' of Class B*, so `ArrayList<B> array;`

> Class A has an association with Class B and Class B, ...

I suppose is *Class A has an association with Class B, ...*

> Class A then passes this array to Class C

I suppose you mean this array is given in argument to an operation of Class C

---

> Class A has an association with Class B, and Class C has a dependency with Class B

- *Class A has an association with Class B* : yes
- *Class C has a dependency with Class B* : yes if C knows it receives (through operation argument) instances of B and 'use' them

---

> Class A has an association with Class B, Class C has an association with Class A, and Class C has a dependency with Class B

- *Class A has an association with Class B* : yes
- *Class C has an association with Class A* : there is nothing in your statement requiring that
- *Class C has a dependency with Class B* : yes if C knows it receives (through operation argument) instances of B and 'use' them